# Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'cmbY' is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting a non-declaration error in this code.

```
    Line 23:         If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    Line 24: cmbY.DataSource = rsFirehose("SELECT LeagueTypeKey, LeagueTypeDescription FROM LeagueType " & _**
    Line 25:                 "WHERE LeagueTypeKey=0 or (Appkey=" & glngAppKey & " AND LeagueTypeKey IN (SELECT Distinct YKey FROM " & _
    Line 26:                 "Division WHERE DivisionTypeKey=" & soaDivisionTypeBracket & ")) ORDER BY LeagueTypeDescription")
```

Line 24 is where the error is: it says that the name "cmbY" is not declared. How do I declare it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. can you share your code?

Comment: Did you have a drop-down list on your page at one point that has now been deleted?

Comment: do you have a control on your page named `cmbY`?

Comment: Hi yes i can share my code, it is a lot of code however, and it's my first time using this site, so what way can i share it, as it won't all fit in this comments box?

Comment: Hi, No i never had a drop-down list on my page.

Comment: Just show your code for *cmbY* on code front.

Comment: @user1827546 click edit to edit your question.

Comment: I'v solved my problem, i declared the name "cmbY" as Dim cmbY

Comment: Your page will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Don't build queries with string concatenation like that. This is a **huge** problem.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this error

1.Check the spelling of the control
2.Check the scope of the element
3.Check the member access operator

If you post your code then we can find it very well...so post your code